# Meaning of integration with respect to a multivariable function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I'm learning the joint distribution of 2 random variables and I see the notation below:   $$\int_{[0,1]^2} xy\,dF(x,y)$$

I would like to ask 2 questions:

1. What does it mean to integrate with respect to $dF(x,y)$ ? Is the above notation a double integration ?
   Could you please suggest me some books or some keyword so that I could read about the meaning and the underlying theory of the above notation (especially the part **with respect to dF(x,y)**)?
2. If I set:
   $f(x,y) = \frac{\partial F(x,y)} {\partial x .\partial y}$
   Can I replace $dF(x,y)$ by $f(x,y) \, dxdy$ to get the equation:
   $$\int_{[0,1]^2} xy\,dF(x,y) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x\,y \, f(x,y) \, dxdy$$
   If yes/no, could you please explain why can (can't) we do this?

Comment: could you share where you saw this dF notation?

Comment: In fact, I've seen this in an article that talks about the Multivariate joint distribution function of random variables. It talks about Copula.

Answer (score 1):

The [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20total%20derivative,not%20just%20a%20single%20one.) looks like this:
$$dF(x,y)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy$$
so maybe it meant this?

Comment: If it means as you said, how do we double integrate it ? I think that we should have $dx.dy$ so that we be able to integrate it ? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes that bit does confuse me too, although it reminds me of the integrals related to brownian motion but I am probably wrong...